# How to use a select option dropdown in an Angular Directive?

Tags: angularjs, select, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-show

**Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/pJRzKn2v1s865w5WZBkR?p=preview**

- I have 2 forms, a simple and advanced form.
- Both have the same options (a lot of options)
- Only a couple of differences in the opening select tag which contains

---

```
<select ng-show="showSimpleSelect"
        ng-model="selected_tag"
        ng-change="changeFormTag(formData)"
        class="form-control manage-source-input-tag">

<!-- if advanced then -->
<select ng-show="showAdvanceSelect"
        ng-model="formData.tag"
        ng-change="changeTag(formData.tag)"
        class="form-control manage-source-input-tag">

            <option value="brand">Brand</option>
            <option value="client">Client</option>
            <option value="companies">Companies</option>
            ...

</select ng-show="showSimpleSelect">
</select ng-show="showAdvanceSelect">
```

In my Directives Controller, I'm using vars like this to show and hide the opening select tags:

```
vs.showSimpleForm = function() {
    vs.showSimpleSelect  = true,
    vs.showAdvanceSelect = false,
```

However the HTML ends up looking like this, which breaks the design:
[image]

How would you go about refactoring this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular overrides the `select` tag as a custom directive that expects an [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute instead of `option` tags. You can just hard-code your options into an array and put that as the `ng-option`

```
//controller
$scope.options = ["brand", "client", "companies"];
//html
<select ng-show="showAdvanceSelect"
        ng-model="formData.tag"
        ng-change="changeTag(formData.tag)"
        ng-options="option for option in options"
        class="form-control manage-source-input-tag">
```

Comment: Oh cool thanks! Nice to know... the problem is my options are exactly the same in both forms. The only things that change are the `ng-model` and `ng-change` in the opening selects.

Comment: @LeonGaban Stick that array in a service, or just define that array in the `link` section of the directive declaration

Comment: @grindberg Hi, still having issues with this, could you take a look at this plunk? http://plnkr.co/edit/pJRzKn2v1s865w5WZBkR?p=preview

Comment: @LeonGaban You should ask this as a new question.

Comment: Ok I'll post that, cause what I was trying to do was update the select, not the options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354751/how-to-change-select-functions-in-angular-directive